# Excel - Find first row where value in one column is greater than the value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have a table of values like:

| Row | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Seattle | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | Portland | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | San Francisco | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | Los Angeles | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | San Diego | 5 | 1 |

Is there a formula in excel for me to find the first **A** going down the list where the value in **B** is greater than or equal to the value in **C**?

For this example, Row 3 is the first row where the value in **B** (3) is greater than or equal to the value in **C** (3), so the value I'd like to return is San Francisco.

I've tried creating a helper column **D** with the formula `IF(B1>=C1, 1, 0)` and dragging that formula down through **D**. Then, I can use `XLOOKUP` to do `XLOOKUP(1,D1:D5,A1:A5)`, but I'd like to avoid cluttering the sheet with the helper column.

Comment: Have you tried in this manner using `FILTER()` Function ? `=FILTER(A1:A5,B1:B5=C1:C5)`  or is it I am thinking in wrong way. Also by using `>=` or `>` it would not only return `San Francisco` but also `Los Angeles` & `San Diego`. And the formula you are trying to use that will return only `Los Angeles` from the given data in Op

Comment: I've edited the original question to use `>=`. Thank you for catching that typo. I'm experimenting with the `FILTER()` function, but that seems promising, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Mayukh Bhattacharya in the comments for the pointer to `FILTER()`. That worked perfectly.

I can create a virtual range with `=FILTER(A1:A5,B1:B5>=C1:C5)`, and then I can use `INDEX()` to find the first row and column of that virtual range:

`=INDEX(FILTER(A1:A5,B1:B5>=C1:C5), 1, 1)`

Comment: If you have access to `TAKE()` function then use `=TAKE(FILTER(A1:A5,B1:B5>=C1:C5),1)` or just `=@FILTER(A1:A5,B1:B5>=C1:C5)` add `implicit intersection` in the beginning of the formula that will return the first value.

Comment: Even better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
=TAKE(FILTER(A1:A5,MAP(B1:B5,C1:C5,LAMBDA(b,c, b>=c))),1)
```

[image]